# How to display start time and stop time

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# programming, I have start button in one class,  Transfer Start and Transfer Stop labels with TextBox in another class. As well as both are in different tabs in the design also. I am able to display start and stop time in the same tab and class but i am not able to display in another class.I have attached simple design as below.![Sample][1]

When i click"start" button in Project tab then it has to display the start time in the textbox with label "transfer start". same with stop button also. I want to display start and stop times. in the project tab i have some other functionality to add but i haven't displayed here.

Comment: I think adding the relevant code to your forms would help us better to help you.

Comment: Create a constructor for your second class that takes the parameters that you want to pass.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a delegate to pass through the value to the second tab/class to avoid cross threading problems etc... something like:

```
MyClass.NotifyParentUI += new EventHandler<MyArgs>(UpdateMyLabel);

 public void UpdateMyLabel(object sender, MyArgs ea)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
            delegate()
            {
                myLabel.Text = ea.Message;
            }));
    }


public class MyArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the class that you want to pass data from use:

```
public MyClass
{
     public static event EventHandler<MyArgs> NotifyParentUI;

     protected virtual void OnMyEvent(MyArgs ea)
     {
         if (NotifyParentUI != null)
         {
             NotifyParentUI(this, ea);
         }
     }
}
```

Using:

```
  OnMyEvent(new MyArgs() { Message = "Transfer start/stop values go here" });
```

To pass the value

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data between forms using various methods [pass data between forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx)

1. Via constructors
2. via global properties
3. via events

if form is same for both tab, then you can use the control itself. what's the problem with that ?

```
public Class form2 {
public form2(string somevalues)
{
 //use this values. in form2 
}
}

public class form1 {
form2 objfrm = new form2("your value");
}
```

Comment: can you describe me more about how to pass data using global properties.